# Merge or concat df's with uneven rows - python

Tags: python, pandas, merge, concatenation

I have three separate data frames. I'm hoping to merge or concat these together. I have a reference value in each data frame. I have labelled them `ValueX, ValueY, ValueZ`. But they don't have unique values to merge on. They almost always contain the same number of corresponding values though.

Using the df below, I'm hoping to align the data frames on `ValueX, ValueY, ValueZ`. The values in each are largely aligned if you concat. but sometimes there are 4 or 6 values instead of 5. So the corresponding data frames aren't aligned.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'ValueX' : [0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,2,2,2,4,4,4,4,4],                   
    'Item3' : ['a', 'e', 'd', 'g', 'f', 'c', 'c', 'f', 'b', 'c', 'j', 'g', 'm', 's', 'c', 'k'], 
    'Item4' : ['f', 's', 'h', 'k', 'f', 'd', 'c', 'g', 'b', 'k', 'j', 'n', 'r', 'd', 'x', 'd'],                         
        })

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'ValueY' : [1,1,1,1,1,3,3,3,3,3,3,5,5,5,5,5,5],                   
    'Item1' : ['a', 'c', 'c', 'g', 'a', 'c', 'c', 'g', 'a', 'c', 'c', 'g', 'a', 'c', 'c', 'g',  'k'], 
    'Item2' : ['a', 'e', 'd', 'g', 'f', 'c', 'c', 'f', 'b', 'c', 'j', 'g', 'm', 's', 'c', 'k',  'k'],                         
        })

df3 = pd.DataFrame({
    'ValueZ' : [6,6,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,7,7,8,8,8,8,8],                  
    'Item5' : ['a', 'e', 'd', 'g', 'f', 'c', 'c', 'f', 'b', 'c', 'j', 'g', 'm', 's', 'c', 'k'], 
    'Item6' : ['f', 's', 'h', 'k', 'f', 'd', 'c', 'g', 'b', 'k', 'j', 'n', 'r', 'd', 'x', 'd'],                         
        })

final_df = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3], axis = 1)
```

Intended output:

```
    ValueX Item3 Item4  ValueY Item1 Item2  ValueZ Item5 Item6
0      0.0     a     f     1.0     a     a     6.0     a     f
1      0.0     e     s     1.0     c     e     6.0     e     s
2      0.0     d     h     1.0     c     d     6.0     d     h
3      0.0     g     k     1.0     g     g     6.0     g     k
4      0.0     f     f     1.0     a     f     6.0     f     f
5      0.0     c     d     NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN   NaN   NaN
6      2.0     c     c     3.0     c     c     7.0     c     d
7      2.0     f     g     3.0     c     c     7.0     c     c
8      2.0     b     b     3.0     g     f     7.0     f     g
9      2.0     c     k     3.0     a     b     7.0     b     b
10     2.0     j     j     3.0     c     c     7.0     c     k
11     NaN   NaN   NaN     3.0     c     j     7.0     j     j
12     4.0     g     n     5.0     g     g     8.0     g     n
13     4.0     m     r     5.0     a     m     8.0     m     r
14     4.0     s     d     5.0     c     s     8.0     s     d
15     4.0     c     x     5.0     c     c     8.0     c     x
16     4.0     k     d     5.0     g     k     8.0     k     d
17     NaN   NaN   NaN     5.0     k     k     NaN   NaN   NaN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `itertools.zip_longest` to align the groups:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

g1 = df1.groupby('ValueX')
g2 = df2.groupby('ValueY')
g3 = df3.groupby('ValueZ')

dfs = []
for (_, a), (_, b), (_, c) in zip_longest(g1, g2, g3, fillvalue=('', pd.DataFrame())):
    dfs.append( 
        pd.concat([a.reset_index(drop=True), 
                   b.reset_index(drop=True), 
                   c.reset_index(drop=True)], axis=1) )

final = pd.concat(dfs).reset_index(drop=True)
print(final)
```

Prints:

```
    ValueX Item3 Item4  ValueY Item1 Item2  ValueZ Item5 Item6
0      0.0     a     f     1.0     a     a     6.0     a     f
1      0.0     e     s     1.0     c     e     6.0     e     s
2      0.0     d     h     1.0     c     d     6.0     d     h
3      0.0     g     k     1.0     g     g     6.0     g     k
4      0.0     f     f     1.0     a     f     6.0     f     f
5      0.0     c     d     NaN   NaN   NaN     NaN   NaN   NaN
6      2.0     c     c     3.0     c     c     7.0     c     d
7      2.0     f     g     3.0     c     c     7.0     c     c
8      2.0     b     b     3.0     g     f     7.0     f     g
9      2.0     c     k     3.0     a     b     7.0     b     b
10     2.0     j     j     3.0     c     c     7.0     c     k
11     NaN   NaN   NaN     3.0     c     j     7.0     j     j
12     4.0     g     n     5.0     g     g     8.0     g     n
13     4.0     m     r     5.0     a     m     8.0     m     r
14     4.0     s     d     5.0     c     s     8.0     s     d
15     4.0     c     x     5.0     c     c     8.0     c     x
16     4.0     k     d     5.0     g     k     8.0     k     d
17     NaN   NaN   NaN     5.0     k     k     NaN   NaN   NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

```
d=[df1,df2,df3]#Put DataFrames in a list
for x in d:
    pd.melt(x, id_vars=','.join(list(x.filter(regex="^Value", axis=1).columns)), value_vars=','.join(list(x.filter(regex="^Item", axis=1).columns)))#x.rename(columns={','.join(list(x.filter(regex=["^Value"#], axis=1).columns)):'Values'}, inplace=True)#Melt the dataframes
final_df = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3], axis = 1)#Concat the dataframes
print(final_df)

    ValueX Item3 Item4  ValueY Item1 Item2  ValueZ Item5 Item6
0      0.0     a     f       1     a     a     6.0     a     f
1      0.0     e     s       1     c     e     6.0     e     s
2      0.0     d     h       1     c     d     6.0     d     h
3      0.0     g     k       1     g     g     6.0     g     k
4      0.0     f     f       1     a     f     6.0     f     f
5      0.0     c     d       3     c     c     7.0     c     d
6      2.0     c     c       3     c     c     7.0     c     c
7      2.0     f     g       3     g     f     7.0     f     g
8      2.0     b     b       3     a     b     7.0     b     b
9      2.0     c     k       3     c     c     7.0     c     k
10     2.0     j     j       3     c     j     7.0     j     j
11     4.0     g     n       5     g     g     8.0     g     n
12     4.0     m     r       5     a     m     8.0     m     r
13     4.0     s     d       5     c     s     8.0     s     d
14     4.0     c     x       5     c     c     8.0     c     x
15     4.0     k     d       5     g     k     8.0     k     d
16     NaN   NaN   NaN       5     k     k     NaN   NaN   NaN
```

Comment: Cheers. Thanks @wwnde

Comment: Happy it was of help. Keep coding